Keycloak Integration (Using SocialiteProviders) with Laravel 11 error; Class Laravel\Socialite\Two\User contains 7 abstract methods and must theref
Im trying to integrate Keycloak to my Laravel 11 application. The plan is to use Keycloak as Authentication Provider for user to login to my system instead of the conventional way of logging in.
i wanted keycloak to handle all the authentication process, and i do not want user table on my apps since i already import all user to my keycloak environment, and planning to make keycloak handle the login process.
however, im getting this error when i try to login to my apps. Im doing this locally on my windows machine. im using socialitekeycloak provider and v11 of laravel.

Class Laravel\Socialite\Two\User contains 7 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifierName, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifier, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthPasswordName, ...)

this is my KeycloakUser model;
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class KeycloakUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    // Add the necessary fields for your user
    protected $fillable = [
        'keycloak_id', 'name', 'email', 'keycloak_token', 'keycloak_refresh_token',
    ];

    // Implement methods required by the Authenticatable interface
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'keycloak_id'; // or 'id' depending on your setup
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->keycloak_id;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return null; // No password required for Keycloak users
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return null; // Optional, if you don't need "remember me" functionality
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // Optional, if you don't need "remember me" functionality
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return ''; // Optional, if you don't need "remember me" functionality
    }
}


and i design my route like below
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/auth/redirect');
});

Route::get('/auth/redirect', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('keycloak')->redirect();
});


Route::get('/auth/callback', function () {
    $keycloakUser = Socialite::driver('keycloak')->user();

    $user = KeycloakUser::updateOrCreate([
        'keycloak_id' => $keycloakUser->id,
    ], [
        'name' => $keycloakUser->name,
        'email' => $keycloakUser->email,
        'keycloak_token' => $keycloakUser->token,
        'keycloak_refresh_token' => $keycloakUser->refreshToken,
    ]);

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect('/dashboard');
});

i dont know what exactly the error means.
Im expecting after user login via keycloak, my app will routed me to /dashboard pages, no error included
